# dialog window MRTK

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I'm creating UI for hololens. I want to add an error message to my login. Thus when the user types a wrong (password or/and username) during login an error message appears. I added the dialog window (belongs to MRTK) as the window for the error message. The problem is that when the error message is appearing, it hides behind the login window. Since the dialog window is not the child to the login window, it is hard to adjust position or the distace to the dialog window from the login window.

The login window have RadialView on the inspector, and the dialog window is using `ConstantViewSize`. On the script I wrote:

```
Dialog d =
Dialog.Open(
dialogPrefab, 
DialogButtonType.OK,
LocalizationSetting.StringDatabase.GetLocalizedString("Error message", "login failed"),
true);

d.gameObject.GetComponent<ConstantViewSize>().MaxDistance = 3f;
```

And here is how it looks like on the Radial View that belongs to the Login window:

[image]

My expectation is to have the dialog window/error message appearing in front of the login window.

Answer (score 0):

[ConstantViewSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.utilities.solvers.constantviewsize?preserve-view=true&view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0) maintains the size of the object in the view by directly modifying the Scale of the object instead of modifying the Position of the object. For your needs, you should configure the [Follow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.utilities.solvers.follow?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0) component in the Dialog prefab to ensure it is in the closest position to the head by setting its Max Distance.

For these solvers, you can refer to [Solver overview - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/solvers/solver?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) to learn more.